# ColdFusion - Booking System - Booking Disappears

Tags: ms-access, coldfusion, append

This code below is a simple booking system, they book/sign up.  Nothing more really.  Problem I am having is if there is multiple users signing up around the same time frame, the `ListAppend` doesn't lock out per say.  So both will sign up. But if at the same time, when the smoke settles, a user may not be signed up.

I am certain this is a `ListAppend` issue, so they hit the site same time, but the append updates and misses someone.

Kinda like that site auction, where you think you are the winner, but at the end of the day you are not.

Is there a simple fix for this?  Using ColdFusion 2016, MS Access.

```
      <cfset signedup = #add.signedup# + 1>

      <cfset temp = ValueList(add.userssigned)>

      <cfset temp2 = ListAppend(Temp, "#session.demshinuser_id#", ",")>

      <cfquery name=Update DATASOURCE="#ds#">
      update shindates
      set 
      signedup = #signedup#,
      userssigned = '#temp2#'
      where shinid = '#shinid#'
      </cfquery>
```

Comment: The issue here is not with `ListAppend` but with your code. When you are dealing with shared scope to determine logic you cannot use local variables or you end up with problems like you are having. Instead you need to use a common place to store and determine when a user signs up. The database will work nicely for that. So first thing you do before signing someone up is make sure someone isn't already. If not, sign that user up in the database (insert or update a record). You could also use ColdFusion's application scope for this but I would recommend a database instead.

Comment: I agree with Miguel-F, but .. can you explain the variables and columns? What is `add.signedup` supposed to contain? What are the columns "signedup" and "userssigned" supposed to contain?

Comment: add.signed up is a number sorry... So it allows 20 to sign up.  If 2 are signed up, when next person signs up... It goes to 3 etc... Once it hits 20, the sign up button disappears... Miguel.. I am using a database, there is a check to be sure they themselves are not already signed up.  As for columns, the signed up is the number... And Userssigned, is the new AppendedList of ID's of who is signed up.

Comment: What is happening is, a user goes to sign up... And hits the signup button, it grabs the current list, he signs up... But if another user signs up around the same time, it grabs the list too, so he signs up, it updates... But basically it updates, the list without the first person signing up on it.  I never had this problem before, I went to ColdFusion2016, is it a server setting?

Comment: No, there's no setting.  The problem is due to a basic race condition: multiple users reading *and* updating a shared value at the same time- only one of them wins.  1. John goes to sign up. The queries report there's 1 user signed up: "Jane".
2. At the same time Bob tries to sign up. The queries report there's currently (1) user signed up: "Jane"
3. John's thread runs the update:  `signedup = 2, usersigned = "Jane,John"`
4. Bob's thread runs the update:  `signedup = 2, usersigned = "Jane,Bob"`.  ----- Bob's update wins.

Comment: Race conditions can apply to any shared resource that's not constructed with concurrent access in mind (variables, database records, etc...)

Comment: Why are you using MS Access, just out of interest? And is there some reason why you are adding an incrementing list of IDs into a single column. You should really split up the IDs, so that each ID occupies a single row. This will allow you to join tables etc Your current DB architecture creates a problem whereby your users are competing for a single row in the DB. You need to rationalise your DB. And I would strongly advise you to use something like MySQL. Very simple to set up and you can convert your Access Database very easily.

Comment: The first thing that popped out at me was a comma-delimited list going into a single database field. This will ultimately cause a lot of headaches for you. If you are at a point where you can refactor the database to not rely on the comma list, I'd do it.

Comment: Agreed about not storing lists. Aside from their other issues, they'll exacerbate a problem like this, but ... even with a more normalized structure, you still need to account for multiple threads inserting/updating at the same time.

Comment: Spot on Ageax... Exactly whats happening... It is a single record.  But creating another multiple row record for every booking would cause a huge database issue would it not?

Comment: (Update): Don't worry about size. That's the way databases are designed to work, and will perform better that way. Plus, it'd normally store integers only, which are very small. Say you're enrolling students in a course. You'd have 3 tables: Courses, Students and Enrollments. The Enrollments table only stores the unique (autonumber) keys for each Course and Student - ie StudentId and CourseId. So it may have many records, but the overall size will be small.

Answer (score 3):

## Issue - Race Conditions

The problem is your current code is subject to race conditions. When multiple threads try and read *and* write a shared resource at the same time, only one of them can win.
This is what happens when "John" an "Bob" try and sign up at the exact same time:

1. John goes to sign up. The queries reports there's only one user signed up so far: "*Jane*".
2. At the same time, Bob goes to sign up.  Since John's thread hasn't completed yet, the query again reports there's only one user signed up: "*Jane*".
3. John's thread updates the record, appending him to the original list of enrolled users: "*Jane,John*".
   [image: John's Update]
4. Then Bob's thread updates the record, also appending him to the original list: "*Jane,Bob*"
   [image: Bob's Update]

**Bob's thread wins and wipes out the changes from John's thread.**

Locking the resource - so only one thread can read and/or modify it at a time - is the ONLY reliable way of fixing the issue.

## Database Structure

Personally, I'd recommend redesigning the table to avoid storing lists. Aside from exacerbating this type of problem, databases simply aren't designed for lists. They work best when data is stored in individual rows. While possible, storing lists creates a host of other problems like data integrity issues and substandard query performance. It's better to create a separate table for storing enrollments as separate records.

Say your application records student enrollments, you'd have 3 tables:

- `CREATE TABLE Course (courseId int identity, courseName varchar(100), ....)`
- `CREATE TABLE Student (studentId int identity, userName varchar(100), ....)`
- `CREATE TABLE Enrollment (courseId int, studentId int)`

Before adding a new record, check the Enrollment table to see if the user is already enrolled, and if so reject it. I don't use Access, but something like this structure will work. Replace the @variables with cfqueryparam.

```
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS EnrollmentsFound
    FROM   Enrollment 
    WHERE  courseId = @courseId
    AND    studentId = @studentId
```

To determine if a course is full, do a `COUNT(*)`. If the count is less than the maximum capacity, allow the INSERT. Otherwise, reject it. With SQL Server you could use do something like below - **with an appropriate [lock](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172398(v=sql.110).aspx) or a serializable transaction.** Without one of those, it's still subject to race conditions. Granted, the window of opportunity is smaller than with your current code, but it still exists.

```
if ((select count(*) from Enrollment where courseId = @courseId) < @maxCapacity) 
begin
    insert into Enrollment (courseId, studentId )
    values (@courseId, @studentId)
end
```

Unfortunately, MS Access probably doesn't support "if exists...", lock hints or transactions. So consider upgrading to SQL Server or MySQL, both of which offer more robust options. If you absolutely can't upgrade, the above could probably be rewritten as two separate queries and a cfif/cfelse. **However you must still apply some sort of locking to avoid race conditions. Locking the resource - so only a single thread may read or modify it at a time - is the ONLY reliable way of fixing the issue**.

Much though I hate to say it, since MS Access doesn't support transactions AFAIK, you could try using an exclusive "named" [CFLOCK](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-j-l/cflock.html) instead of a serializable transaction. It'll work, but frankly it's a poor substitute for real database transactions. So again, if at all possible, better to upgrade to a more solid database which provides proper transaction support IMO.

```
<!--- Exclusive lock to prevent race conditions / Access ONLY --->
<cflock name="Student_Enrollment_Add" type="exclusive" timeout="5000">

   <cfquery name="getEnrollments" ...>
      SELECT COUNT(*) AS EnrollmentsFound
      FROM   Enrollment 
      WHERE  courseId = <cfqueryparam value="#form.courseId#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
   </cfquery>

   <cfif getEnrollments.EnrollmentsFound lt maxCapacity>
       <cfquery ...>
          INSERT INTO Enrollment ( .... )
          VALUES ( .... )
       </cfquery>
   </cfif>

</cflock>
```

Comment: Ageax : yes these checks are made and the counts are made too. cfif add.userssigned does not contain "#session.demshinuser_id#" : this checks to see if they are on the list.  The problem is the Race Issue.  Hmmm... I'm thinking of putting in random time pauses, so they hit the button to book, takes them to a holding page for say 5 seconds.  Then they submit again, might aggravate people, but fixes the race issue.  Creating a seperate booking table with multiple lines might work.  But then that will cause some big database problems if I'm not purging the data.

Comment: Locking the resource, so only one thread can read/write at the same time is the only reliable way of fixing the issue.  Much though I hate to say it, since Access doesn't support transactions, you could try a "named" `cflock` instead.  I wouldn't be concerned with multiple records, unless you plan on having millions of records - in which case MS Access probably wouldn't be the right tool anyway. Storing individual records - not lists - is the way database's are supposed to be structured, and results in easier querying, not to mention better and more reliable performance than storing lists.

Comment: (Update) *"Then they submit again, might aggravate people, but fixes the race issue."* Unfortunately, that won't fix the issue, just prolong the inevitable. Sooner or later the same thing will happen again.. The only sure way to prevent it is by locking. Since MS Access doesn't support proper transactions, you'll have to try an exclusive named CFLOCK (see updated answer). Though again, I'd strongly suggest redesigning the table. Do a search on storing lists and you'll find many examples of why it's considered a poor design and is not recommended.